# I want to get the sunday WeekNo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to get the Sunday weekno and I already have the query but it shows the wrong data. What can I do ?

It shows 2 instead of 1. For example, 06-Jan-2013(WeekNo - 1)

My query is

```
SELECT DATEPART (week, '01-13-2013 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo1 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '01-06-2013 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo2 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-30-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo3 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-23-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo4 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-16-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo5 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-09-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7915)**

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
SELECT DATEPART (week, '01-13-2013 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo1 ,  
       DATEPART (week, '01-06-2013 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo2 , 
       DATEPART (week, '12-30-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo3 ,  
       DATEPART (week, '12-23-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo4 ,  
       DATEPART (week, '12-16-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo5 ,  
       DATEPART (week, '12-09-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo6
```

Result:

```
| WEEKNO1 | WEEKNO2 | WEEKNO3 | WEEKNO4 | WEEKNO5 | WEEKNO6 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       2 |       1 |      53 |      52 |      51 |      50 |
```

Comment: The initial/original `DATEFIRST` setting should be restored after `SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) property to the start day of the week. This specifies the first day of the week.

To determine what your server's first day of the week is, you will use:

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
```

Then if you need to change the value, you would use:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT DATEPART (week, '01-13-2013 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo1 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '01-06-2013 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo2 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-30-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo3 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-23-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo4 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-16-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo5 ,  
  DATEPART (week, '12-09-2012 23:59:59.000' ) As WeekNo6
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7914).